# How to apply numpy.linalg.norm to each row of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D matrix and I want to take norm of each row. But when I use `numpy.linalg.norm(X)` directly, it takes the norm of the whole matrix.

I can take norm of each row by using a for loop and then taking norm of each `X[i]`, but it takes a huge time since I have 30k rows.

Any suggestions to find a quicker way? Or is it possible to apply `np.linalg.norm` to each row of a matrix?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

### For numpy 1.9+

Note that, as [perimosocordiae shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19794741/190597), as of NumPy version 1.9, `np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)` is the fastest way to compute the L2-norm.

### For numpy < 1.9

If you are computing an L2-norm, you could compute it directly (using the `axis=-1` argument to sum along rows):

```
np.sum(np.abs(x)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)
```

Lp-norms can be computed similarly of course.

It is considerably faster than `np.apply_along_axis`, though perhaps not as convenient:

```
In [48]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 208 us per loop

In [49]: %timeit np.sum(np.abs(x)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 us per loop
```

Other `ord` forms of `norm` can be computed directly too (with similar speedups):

```
In [55]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda row:np.linalg.norm(row,ord=1), 1, x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 203 us per loop

In [54]: %timeit np.sum(abs(x), axis=-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.9 us per loop
```

Comment: Why do you do np.abs(x) if you square x anyway?

Comment: @Patrick: If the dtype of `x` is complex, then it makes a difference. For example, if `x = np.array([(1+1j,2+1j)])` then `np.sum(np.abs(x)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)` is `array([ 2.64575131])`, while `np.sum(x**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)` is `array([ 2.20320266+1.36165413j])`.

Comment: @perimosocordiae [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19794741/1959808) an update that [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) with its [new](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3387) `axis` argument is currently the fastest approach.

Comment: How to do the same If I want to apply norm column-wise to a matrix?

Comment: @user3515225: `np.linalg.norm(x, axis=0)`. The `axis` refers to the axis being summed over. For a 2D array, the 0-axis refers to rows, so `axis=0` causes `norm` to sum down the rows for each fixed column.

Answer (score 60):

Resurrecting an old question due to a numpy update. As of the 1.9 release, `numpy.linalg.norm` now accepts an `axis` argument. [[code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3387), [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)]

This is the new fastest method in town:

```
In [10]: x = np.random.random((500,500))

In [11]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, x)
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit np.sum(np.abs(x)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop
```

And to prove it's calculating the same thing:

```
In [14]: np.allclose(np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1), np.sum(np.abs(x)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2))
Out[14]: True
```

Answer (score 27):

Much faster than the accepted answer is using NumPy's [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html),

```py
numpy.sqrt(numpy.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, a))
```

And even faster than that is arranging the data such that the norms are computed across all *columns*,

```py
numpy.sqrt(numpy.einsum('ij,ij->j', aT, aT))
```

Note the log-scale:

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)


def setup(n):
    x = rng.random((n, 3))
    xt = np.ascontiguousarray(x.T)
    return x, xt


def sum_sqrt(a, _):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(a) ** 2, axis=-1))


def apply_norm_along_axis(a, _):
    return np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, a)


def norm_axis(a, _):
    return np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)


def einsum_sqrt(a, _):
    return np.sqrt(np.einsum("ij,ij->i", a, a))


def einsum_sqrt_columns(_, aT):
    return np.sqrt(np.einsum("ij,ij->j", aT, aT))


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[
        sum_sqrt,
        apply_norm_along_axis,
        norm_axis,
        einsum_sqrt,
        einsum_sqrt_columns,
    ],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
b.show()
b.save("out.png")
```

Comment: Care to explain what that is/does?

Comment: einsum never fails to deliver :)

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
In [16]: numpy.apply_along_axis(numpy.linalg.norm, 1, a)
Out[16]: array([ 5.38516481,  1.41421356,  5.38516481])
```

where `a` is your 2D array.

The above computes the L2 norm. For a different norm, you could use something like:

```
In [22]: numpy.apply_along_axis(lambda row:numpy.linalg.norm(row,ord=1), 1, a)
Out[22]: array([9, 2, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this, when your 2D numpy array is `x`:

```
x_unit = x / np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```