# How do you get the magnitude of a vector in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

In keeping with the "There's only one obvious way to do it", how do you get the magnitude of a vector (1D array) in Numpy?

```
def mag(x): 
    return math.sqrt(sum(i**2 for i in x))
```

The above works, but I *cannot believe* that I must specify such a trivial and core function myself.

Comment: I usually use `linalg.norm` as mentioned below.  But slightly simpler than your lambda thing, with no imports needed, is just `sum(x*x)**0.5`

Comment: The link is dead! [Long live the link!](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.ppt)

Comment: The link is PowerPoint! [Long live the PDF!](https://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf)

Answer (score 327, accepted):

The function you're after is [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html). (I reckon it should be in base numpy as a property of an array -- say `x.norm()` -- but oh well).

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
np.linalg.norm(x)
```

You can also feed in an optional `ord` for the nth order norm you want. Say you wanted the 1-norm:

```
np.linalg.norm(x,ord=1)
```

And so on.

Comment: "Should be a property of an array: x.norm()" I totally agree. Usually when working with numpy I use my own Array and Matrix subclasses that have all functions I commonly use pulled in as methods.  `Matrix.randn([5,5])`

Comment: Also, for matrices comprised of vectors, `np.linalg.norm` now has a new `axis` argument, discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19794741/1959808

Answer (score 131):

If you are worried at all about speed, you should instead use:

```
mag = np.sqrt(x.dot(x))
```

Here are some benchmarks:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('np.linalg.norm(x)', setup='import numpy as np; x = np.arange(100)', number=1000)
0.0450878
>>> timeit.timeit('np.sqrt(x.dot(x))', setup='import numpy as np; x = np.arange(100)', number=1000)
0.0181372
```

EDIT: The real speed improvement comes when you have to take the norm of many vectors. Using pure numpy functions doesn't require any for loops. For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(1200.0).reshape((-1,3))

In [3]: %timeit [np.linalg.norm(x) for x in a]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.23 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.sqrt((a*a).sum(axis=1))
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.9 us per loop

In [5]: np.allclose([np.linalg.norm(x) for x in a],np.sqrt((a*a).sum(axis=1)))
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: I did actually use this slightly-less-explicit method after finding that `np.linalg.norm` was a bottleneck, but then I went one step further and just used `math.sqrt(x[0]**2 + x[1]**2)` which was another significant improvement.

Comment: @NickT, see my edit for the real improvement when using pure numpy functions.

Comment: Cool application of the dot product!

Comment: `numpy.linalg.norm` contains safeguards against overflow that this implementation skips. For instance, try computing the norm of `[1e200, 1e200]`. There is a reason if it is slower...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, at least with numpy version 1.13.3 I get `inf` when computing `np.linalg.norm([1e200,1e200])`.

Comment: @user545424 Interesting, I checked and I confirm your findings with my current version. Must be a regression? With Matlab, I get correctly `norm([1e200, 1e200]) == 1.4142e+200`.

Answer (score 20):

Yet another alternative is to use the `einsum` function in numpy for either arrays:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(1200.0).reshape((-1,3))

In [3]: %timeit [np.linalg.norm(x) for x in a]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.86 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.sqrt((a*a).sum(axis=1))
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.71 µs per loop
```

or vectors:

```
In [5]: a = np.arange(100000)

In [6]: %timeit np.sqrt(a.dot(a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.8 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('i,i', a, a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.6 µs per loop
```

There does, however, seem to be some overhead associated with calling it that may make it slower with small inputs:

```
In [2]: a = np.arange(100)

In [3]: %timeit np.sqrt(a.dot(a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.73 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('i,i', a, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.68 µs per loop
```

Comment: `numpy.linalg.norm` contains safeguards against overflow that this implementation skips. For instance, try computing the norm of `[1e200, 1e200]`. There is a reason if it is slower...

Answer (score 9):

Fastest way I found is via inner1d. Here's how it compares to other numpy methods:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

V = np.random.random_sample((10**6,3,)) # 1 million vectors
A = np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', V, V))
B = np.linalg.norm(V,axis=1)   
C = np.sqrt((V ** 2).sum(-1))
D = np.sqrt((V*V).sum(axis=1))
E = np.sqrt(inner1d(V,V))

print [np.allclose(E,x) for x in [A,B,C,D]] # [True, True, True, True]

import cProfile
cProfile.run("np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', V, V))") # 3 function calls in 0.013 seconds
cProfile.run('np.linalg.norm(V,axis=1)')              # 9 function calls in 0.029 seconds
cProfile.run('np.sqrt((V ** 2).sum(-1))')             # 5 function calls in 0.028 seconds
cProfile.run('np.sqrt((V*V).sum(axis=1))')            # 5 function calls in 0.027 seconds
cProfile.run('np.sqrt(inner1d(V,V))')                 # 2 function calls in 0.009 seconds
```

inner1d is ~3x faster than linalg.norm and a hair faster than einsum

Comment: Actually from what you write above, `linalg.norm` is the fastest since it does 9 calls in 29ms so 1 call in 3.222ms vs. 1 call in 4.5ms for `inner1d`.

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse the timing for total execution time. If you run the code above you'll get a breakdown of timing per function call. If you still have doubts, change the vector count to something very very large, like `((10**8,3,))` and then manually run `np.linalg.norm(V,axis=1)` followed by `np.sqrt(inner1d(V,V))`, you'll notice `linalg.norm` will lag compared to inner1d

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: `numpy.linalg.norm` contains safeguards against overflow that this implementation skips. For instance, try computing the norm of `[1e200, 1e200]`. There is a reason if it is slower...

Comment: Is `numpy.core.umath_tests.inner1d` the same as `numpy.inner` for this purpose? Maybe the latter is new? or slower?

Comment: @LarsH unfortunately it is not. And it looks like `numpy.core.umath_tests` is getting deprecated. If inner1d's existing functionality goes out into the sunset (which would be a shame) then your best bet (for speed) will be to write a parallelized function using `numba`.

Answer (score 3):

use the function ***norm*** in **scipy.linalg** (or **numpy.linalg**)

```
>>> from scipy import linalg as LA
>>> a = 10*NP.random.randn(6)
>>> a
  array([  9.62141594,   1.29279592,   4.80091404,  -2.93714318,
          17.06608678, -11.34617065])
>>> LA.norm(a)
    23.36461979210312

>>> # compare with OP's function:
>>> import math
>>> mag = lambda x : math.sqrt(sum(i**2 for i in x))
>>> mag(a)
     23.36461979210312
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy and it supports single values and stacked vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
mag1 = np.linalg.norm(x)
mag2 = vg.magnitude(x)
print mag1 == mag2
# True
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are far too verbose in NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

Given an example of a single 5D vector:

```
x = np.array([1,-2,3,-4,5])
```

Typically you code this:

```
from scipy import linalg 
mag = linalg.norm(x)
```

For different types of input (matrices or a stack (batch) of 5D vectors) check the reference documentation which describes the API consistently.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

OR

If the virtual environment is fresh and `scipy` is missing just type

```
mag = np.sqrt(x.dot(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

> take square of each index,then sum, then take sqrt.

```
import numpy as np  

def magnitude(v):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(v))) 
print(magnitude([3,4]))
```