# How to improve the performance of this tiny distance Python function

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm running into a performance bottleneck when using a custom distance metric function for a clustering algorithm from `sklearn`.

The result as shown by Run Snake Run is this:

[image]

Clearly the problem is the `dbscan_metric` function. The function looks very simple and I don't quite know what the best approach to speeding it up would be:

```
def dbscan_metric(a,b):
  if a.shape[0] != NUM_FEATURES:
    return np.linalg.norm(a-b)
  else:
    return np.linalg.norm(np.multiply(FTR_WEIGHTS, (a-b)))
```

Any thoughts as to what is causing it to be this slow would be much appreciated.

Comment: how big are those arrays? if you get rid of the if statement and enforce one of the two statements for the dataset does that speed it up?  ... you could try `len(a) != NUM_FEATURES` instead and see if thats any faster ...

Comment: the answer depends on how big the arrays a and b are. also which numpy version are you using? given the profile they are probably small and you are dominated by python overhead, in that case you would need to use cython to reduce that

Comment: Does it seem odd that 71 sec are spent in norm@linalg.py and 170 sec are spent elsewhere? I thought I knew how to make sense of this diagram, but that just seems odd. All I can guess is that the extra 170 sec are somehow involved in call overhead. Could you try inlining?

Comment: The out of local scope lookup of NUM_FEATURES and FTR_WEIGHTS might also be taking a while

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I tried len(a) as well and it was similar. The arrays are not that big; NUM_FEATURES is 130. I believe my entire dataset is like that, but for some reason `sklearn` sometimes calls the function with a smaller length, which is why I had to add the length check.

Comment: @jtaylor: I'm using numpy 1.6.2; the arrays a and b should be 130 floats each. I'll look into cython, but if it's calling overhead wouldn't it just call back into numpy (which I don't think is compiled) anyway?

Comment: @user1245262: the function is passed to sklearn as a callable so I can't inline it as far as I know.

Comment: You can probably speed it up a bit by following the advice in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171158/how-do-you-get-the-magnitude-of-a-vector-in-numpy/9184560#9184560.

Comment: @user545424: just tried that and it is indeed a bit faster (220 seconds vs 245), but still nowhere near the speed I'd like

Comment: @sirlark: update: moving the two constants to local scope didn't help much either

Comment: @houbysoft, what is the shape and size of the arrays? I think you are probably limited by the overhead of calling python functions with such small arrays. For 1D arrays of size 100, you are still about a factor of 10 off of pure C performance. It's not until you start getting arrays with sizes > 10,000 where they are almost equal.+

Comment: @user545424: yeah, they're 1D arrays of size 130 each. I suppose I'll just precompute the distance matrix for all of them, instead of passing a callable to calculate the distance on demand.

Comment: @user545424 NumPy's `norm` has been changed to do exactly that in recent versions (1.8.0, I think).

Comment: You might try [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771). That way you can find out if you're calling the low-level function more than you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with what the function does - but is there a possibility of repeated calculations? If so, you could memoize the function:

```
cache = {}
def dbscan_metric(a,b):

  diff = a - b

  if a.shape[0] != NUM_FEATURES:
    to_calc = diff
  else:
    to_calc = np.multiply(FTR_WEIGHTS, diff)

  if not cache.get(to_calc): cache[to_calc] = np.linalg.norm(to_calc)

  return cache[to_calc]
```