# Calculate euclidean norm of 100 points of n-dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list of 100 values in python where each value in the list corresponds to an n-dimensional list.

For e.g

```
x=[[1 2],[2 3]] is a 2d list
```

I want to compute euclidean norm over all such points. Is there a standard method to do this?

Comment: so a 3d value would be y = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]?

Comment: @zzk Yes that would be correct

Comment: huh.. maybe it should be y=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].. assuming the first[1,2,3] is a point and the second [1,2,3] is another point in 3d..

Comment: By *distance over all such points*, do you mean distance from the origin (i.e.the magnitude of each n-dimensional vector), or do you mean distances of all the points from each other?

Comment: I mean the Euclidean Norm

Comment: You are correct, typo on my side @zzk

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741878/how-to-apply-numpy-linalg-norm-to-each-row-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 1):

I found this on scipy and this works.
[scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist)

Comment: I second this approach when the calculation takes too much time due to the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If I have interpreted the question correctly, then you have a list of 100 n-dimensional vectors, and you would like a list of their (Euclidean) norms.

I think using numpy is easiest (and quickest!) here,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(x)
np.sqrt((a*a).sum(axis=1))
```

If the vectors do not have equal dimension, or if you want to avoid numpy, then perhaps,

```
[sum([i*i for i in vec])**0.5 for vec in x]
```

or,

```
import math
[math.sqrt(sum([i*i for i in vec])) for vec in x]
```

---

**Edit**: Not entirely sure what you were asking for. So, alternatively: it looks like you have a list, each element of which is an n-dimensional vector, and you want the Euclidean distance between each consecutive pair.  With numpy (assuming n is fixed),

```
x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [8,9,10], [13,14,15] ] # 3D example.
import numpy as np
a = np.array(x)
sqrDiff = (a[:-1] - a[1:])**2
np.sqrt(sqrDiff.sum(axis=1))
```

where the last line returns,

```
array([ 5.19615242, 6.92820323, 8.66025404])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from math import sqrt
valueList = [[[1,2], [2,3]], [[2,2], [3,3]]]

def distance(valueList):
  resultList = []
  for (point1, point2) in valueList:
    resultList.append(sqrt(sum(map(lambda (x1, x2): (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2), zip(point1, point2)))))

  return resultList

print distance(valueList)
```

output is
[1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951]

Here is valuelist contains 2 values, but no problem with 100 values..

Comment: How will you write it for 100 values?

Comment: It should have already worked.. just call distance(your-100-value-list). assuming each of your value is 2 points in n dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to compute the euclidean norm of each row:

```
>>> a = np.arange(200.).reshape((100,2))
>>> a
array([[   0.,    1.],
       [   2.,    3.],
       [   4.,    5.],
       [   6.,    7.],
       [   8.,    9.],
       [  10.,   11.],
       ...
>>> np.sum(a**2,axis=-1) ** .5
array([   1.        ,    3.60555128,    6.40312424,    9.21954446,
         12.04159458,   14.86606875,   17.69180601,   20.51828453,
         23.34523506,   26.17250466,   29.        ,   31.82766093,
         34.6554469 ,   37.48332963,   40.31128874,   43.13930922,
         45.96737974,   48.7954916 ,   51.623638  ,   54.45181356,
         ...
```