# Calculating norm of columns as vectors in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am looking for the best way of calculating the norm of columns as vectors in a matrix.
My code right now is like this but I am sure it can be made better(with maybe numpy?):

```
import numpy as np
def norm(a):
    ret=np.zeros(a.shape[1])
    for i in range(a.shape[1]):
        ret[i]=np.linalg.norm(a[:,i])
    return ret

a=np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
print norm(a)
```

Which returns:

```
[ 2.23606798  5.        ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741878/how-to-apply-numpy-linalg-norm-to-each-row-of-a-matrix Can be done with np.linalg.norm(a, axis=0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the norm by using ufuncs:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(a*a, axis=0))
```

Comment: Thank, may I add that `np.square(a)` may be more comfy when using something complicated instead of `a`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for complex matrices. The correct solution is to use `np.linalg.norm` as in the next answer.

Answer (score 3):

Direct solution using numpy:

```
x = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=0)
```

Comment: this method does not exist with my numy install, and I can't find any documentation about it online. Could you provide some reference ?

Comment: @mattiasbe see [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)