# How to apply a function to all the column of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

It should be a standard question but I am not able find the answer :(

I have a numpy darray n samples (raw) and p variables (observation).
 I would like to count how many times each variables is non 0.

I would use a function like

```
sum([1 for i in column if i!=0])
```

but how can I apply this function to all the columns of my matrix?

Comment: Just a tip - `sum` supports generator expressions.  So, you can just do this: `sum(1 for i in column if i!=0)`.  Actually, if you only have integers, you can do this `sum(1 for i in column if i)`, since `0` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from this post: [How to apply numpy.linalg.norm to each row of a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741878/how-to-apply-numpy-linalg-norm-to-each-row-of-a-matrix)

If the operation supports `axis`, use the `axis` parameter, it's usually faster,

Otherwise, [`np.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) could help.

Here is the [`numpy.count_nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html).

So here is the simple answer:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.eye(3)
np.apply_along_axis(np.count_nonzero, 0, arr)
```

Comment: This is good for my problem. Does it works also with lambda function?

Comment: @Donbeo I think so, any function could be used.  Maybe have a try.

Comment: Some functions such as `np.nanquantile()` is much faster using `np.apply_along_axis()` rather than passing the axis parameter to `np.nanquantile()`. Other functions may depend. If speed is an issue, it may pay to profile and compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.sum` over a boolean array created from comparing your original array to zero, using the `axis` keyword argument to indicate whether you want to count over rows or columns. In your case:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> np.sum(a != 0, axis=0)
array([1, 2, 1, 0])
```