# Fastest computation of distances in rectangular array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, distance

I'm looking for the fastest way to compute a lot of distances from some origin in a an image to every other point. Right now, what I have is something like this:

```
origin = [some_val,some_other_val]
y,x = np.mgrid[:image.shape[0],:image.shape[1]].astype(float)    
r = np.hypot(y-origin[0],x-origin[1])
```

Is there a faster way? I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22721540), but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: ... what is a rectangular array?

Comment: I meant to convey that I all the distances I want are within some rectangular space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's bring some [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play -

```
m,n= image.shape
r = np.sqrt((np.arange(m)[:,None]-origin[0])**2 + (np.arange(n)-origin[1])**2)
```

**Runtime tests and verify results**

Define functions -

```
In [115]: def broadcasting_based(origin,image_shape):
     ...:     m,n= image_shape
     ...:     return np.sqrt((np.arange(m)[:,None]-origin[0])**2 + (np.arange(n)-origin[1])**2)
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: def original_approach(origin,image_shape):
     ...:     y,x = np.mgrid[:image_shape[0],:image_shape[1]].astype(float)    
     ...:     return np.hypot(y-origin[0],x-origin[1])
     ...:
```

Case # 1:

```
In [116]: origin = np.array([100,200])

In [117]: np.allclose(broadcasting_based(origin,[500,500]),original_approach(origin,[500,500]))
Out[117]: True

In [118]: %timeit broadcasting_based(origin,[500,500])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.28 ms per loop

In [119]: %timeit original_approach(origin,[500,500])
10 loops, best of 3: 21.2 ms per loop
```

Case # 2:

```
In [123]: origin = np.array([1000,2000])

In [124]: np.allclose(broadcasting_based(origin,[5000,5000]),original_approach(origin,[5000,5000]))
Out[124]: True

In [125]: %timeit broadcasting_based(origin,[5000,5000])
1 loops, best of 3: 460 ms per loop

In [126]: %timeit original_approach(origin,[5000,5000])
1 loops, best of 3: 2.96 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers, you should definitely answer the question whether you need the distance, or *if your problem can be solved with just the square of the distance*.  E.g. if you want to know the nearest one, this can be perfectly done with the square.

This would save you an expensive square root calculation for each point pair.