# What is the most efficient way to create a 'difference matrix' i.e., the difference between each row and all others?

Tags: matrix, numpy

I have a square matrix of like this:

```
[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
 [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
 [ 7.,  8.,  9.]]
```

and want a matrix like this:

```
[[0.,   27., 108.],
 [27.,   0.,  27.],
 [108., 27.,   0.]]
```

which contains the (here: squared euclidean) distance between each row vector and the other rows in the columns.

What is the most efficient way of creating such a matrix? Is there a way to do this with a "clever" Numpy operation, perhaps without explicit iteration?

Comment: This is more of a programming question; try stackoverflow.

Comment: I think it's a bit of both.  There is also some statistical theory involved. Surely this matrix has a name, and there are ways to exploit the symmetry, etc.

Comment: I think this is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22721540/2336654).

Comment: There's [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(x, metric='sqeuclidean')`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), but I don't think it does anything clever.

Comment: You can use `squareform` on top of `pdist` to create a 2D array : `squareform(pdist(A,'sqeuclidean'))`.