# Fastest method to get max distance of a row from all other rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns "X" and "Y".  I want to obtain for each row the single maximum distance from all other rows.  I know I can do this with nested loops such as:

```
for i_df,row in df.iterrows():
    max_dist=0
    for i_others,other_row in df.iterrows():
        xdiff = row.X - other_row.X
        ydiff = row.Y - other_row.Y
        dist = np.sqrt(xdiff**2 + ydiff**2)
        if dist>max_dist:
            max_dist=dist
    df.loc['max_dist'][i_df]=max_dist
```

Is there a computationally faster or more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Various techniques for calculating all the pairwise distances in a numpy array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720864/efficiently-calculating-a-euclidean-distance-matrix-using-numpy. So one option is `df.to_numpy()`, then an appropriate solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) to get arrays of all the [*distances*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), then compute their [`max`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)*es* :

```
#pip install scipy
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

df["max_dist"] = cdist(df[["X", "Y"]], df[["X", "Y"]]).max(axis=1)
```